# Error processing request => Magento admin page => Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted

Tags: error

I have problem when I want to open admin of magento website. It display this message and admin page not display.

There has been an error processing your request

```
Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted
Trace:
#0 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(777): Zend_Uri::factory('admin/')
#1 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(611): Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
#2 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/Mage.php(382): Mage_Core_Model_Store->getBaseUrl('skin', NULL)
#3 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php(349): Mage::getBaseUrl('skin', NULL)
#4 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php(503): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->getSkinBaseUrl(Array)
#5 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(1035): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->getSkinUrl('reset.css', Array)
#6 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml(32): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getSkinUrl('reset.css') 
#7 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home1/rajlosan...')
#8 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#9 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#10 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#11 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#14 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#16 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php(82): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout() 
#17 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController->loginAction()
#18 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#19 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http) )
#20 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /home1/rajlosan/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store') 
#23 {main}
```

Error log record number: 944127562686

Please tell me what is problem how to slove it.

Comment: Check if base_url in core_config_data is correct. If not, then correct it and clear cache and try again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have the wrong value for secure base url. It should be something like

```
http://www.full.url/
```

(Remember to include that trailing slash)

It looks like your current value for secure base url is `admin/` - which is incorrect.

Also: It would be helpful if your supply your Magento version next time you ask a question.

EDIT:

To fix this without access to back end, you can run the following MySQL query:

```
update core_config_data set value = 'http://your.siteurl.withslash/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

NOTE: above query will update URL on all stores if you have a multi site installation. Update if necessary.

Comment: Not fixI run this query in mysql
update core_config_data set value = 'http://your.siteurl.withslash/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';
but same issue

Comment: You have to replace `'http://your.siteurl.withslash/'` with your own site's home URL. Did you do that? And I see extra semicolons in your query. Do it _exactly_ like this: `update core_config_data set value = 'http://your.siteurl.withslash/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';` Replace `http://your.siteurl.withslash/` with your own url.

Comment: I added with my own web address like  update core_config_data set value = 'http://www.rajlosangeles.com/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';

but same problem on admin page.

Comment: Again I see some problems: 1) You must include the `http://` portion. 2) You have a semicolon before `where`. Remove it.

Comment: Not fixed I run this query in mysql 
update core_config_data set value = 'http://rajlosangeles.com/' where path = 'web/secure/base_url';

0 rows affected. ( Query took 0.0130 sec )
this query return.
Please tell me how to fix it.
I also add http:// before web address and its not have semicolon before where it show only here in comment

Comment: My Store address working fine but admin page not accessible this error show on admin page.

Comment: My Store address is :http://rajlosangeles.com/
Admin Address is : http://rajlosangeles.com/index.php/admin/